# How to set useState const to value of input on change

Tags: html, reactjs

say i created a variable in a functional component like so:

```
const [quizName, setQuizName] = useState("");
```

How could I change this value based on what a user enters into an input. My idea was this:

```
<input
    value={quizName}
    onChange={setQuizName(value)}
></input>
```

But it does not know what value is, how can i get the value into my quizName variable?

Comment: Add an inline function and grab the event target's value: `onChange={(e) => setQuizName(e.target.value)}`. And don't forget to check this: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: <input
    value={quizName}
    onChange={(e) => setQuizName(e.target.value)}
></input>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle an input with React hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757761/handle-an-input-with-react-hooks)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input
    value={quizName}
    onChange={(e)=>setQuizName(e.target.value)}>
</input>
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is to have a function in onChange of input like:

```
<input value={quizName} onChange={(e)=>setQuizName(e.target.value)} />
```

Its okay!, But Please for the sake of GOD please stop doing this!

### Here is the reason:

you are creating a function on every change of input and running it! this is not ok of performance vise! especially if you do it in a large scale app every where in your components!

what you need to do is just use `useCallback` like below:

```
const [quizName, setQuizName] = useState("");

const handleInputChange = useCallback((e) => {
   setQuizName(e.target.value)
}, [setQuizName])


return (
   <input value={quizName} onChange={handleInputChange} />
)
```

here is a description of `useCallback` in react documentations:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={setQuizName(value)}
```

When you call the function like this, it will get executed without waiting you to change it.

```
onChange={(e) => setQuizName(e.target.value)}
```

is the correct way to do it