# How to get first input value in react onChange and use it in onChange?

Tags: reactjs

I can't make react onChange to fire on the first keystroke, the second input works. My goal is to get the new fName value to be used in other functions.

```
export default function Name() {
  const [fName, setfName] = React.useState("");

  return (
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="First Name"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setfName(e.target.value);
          console.log("fname", fName);

          someOtherFunctions(fName); // i need to keep the function here to react to each user input change. how to get the right fName value here? 
        }}
      />

}
```

Typing 'abcd' and console prints:

```
fname 
fname a
fname ab
fname abc
```

Comment: try console.log(e.target.value)

Comment: @zainuldin im in new to react useEffect, not sure how to code it. can you give an example (i updated my code too)

Comment: pass e.target.value to function that's it

Comment: @zainuldin if that's the thing, what's the point of setfName

Comment: you can't update you're value in UI with out using useState

Comment: pass e.targe.value directly to function there solves the problem. is it the good practice to do such? or shall i use useEffect somewhere and get the value and pass in the function?

Comment: you can pass e.target.value to function it's totally fine. useEffect is only used when you want to update value inside UI also

Comment: if you don't want to use value in UI then you can use simple javascript type instead of useState

Comment: well yes i do need to display the value inside UI too.. can you kindly show me how to do it with useEffect? the answers below aren't really helpful..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242903/discussion-between-zain-ul-din-and-user3810193).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this approach do `console.log` before of return whenever state will change it will re-render the page. Have a look at this code

```
import "./styles.css";
import React , {useState , useEffect} from 'react'


export default function App() {
  const [fName, setfName] = useState("");

 // every time state change react will automatically re-render the page
// console.log(fName)
 
function PrintMyState(state){
   console.log(state)
}
 
// calls whenever state will be change , another approach
useEffect( ()=>{ PrintMyState(fName) } , [fName] ) 

 return (

  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="First Name"
    onChange={(e) => {
     setfName(e.target.value)
    }}
   />
 );
}
```

> sand Box Demo [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/new?file=/src/App.js:0-331)

Comment: it is not what i was trying to solve .. thx anyway

Comment: what you are trying to slove please explain

Comment: your question was react useState is not taking 1st input but now it's working

Comment: try to get the right fName value inside the onChange function. (see my updated code comment)

Comment: it's not possible i think react state take some time to update

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs state is asynchronously updated, and batching within the function. So logging within the function itself the last state `""` will be printed.

--> Try moving `console.log("fname", fName);` right before your `return` function.

Answer (score -2):

`onChange` function is fired in every keystroke. It looks like you misunderstand something about React `Hooks`. In your code, setfName is working asynchronously, so first console log prints the previous fName. `console.log("fname", fName + e.target.value);` will print current value correctly. or You can use `useEffect` hook to print current value.

Comment: i think i understand but not sure how to fix it, if my goal is to get the new fName value to be used in other functions.

Comment: @user3810193 you can pass it by props to other components

Answer (score -2):

you need to put `value={fName}` for the `input` to work:

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={fName}
  placeholder="First Name"
  onChange={(e) => {
      setfName(e.target.value);
      console.log("fname", e.target.value);
  }}
/>
```

for logging, run a `useEffect` call that runs everytime `fName` changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(fName)
}, [fName])
```

the dependency array `[fName]` means that run the function inside `useEffect`, in this case `console.log(fName)` every time `fName` changes.

Comment: this is not the problem..

Comment: @user3810193 did you try it?

Comment: yes, still get the same console.log

Comment: @user3810193 nope, it should work. try making a codesandbox or something. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211012/6141587 or https://sebhastian.com/react-onchange/

Comment: @user3810193 i misread your question. i thought input wasn't working. added an explanation for `console.log` to work using `useEffect`. since react state is asynchronous, you can't access it directly inside `onChange` call. you must run a useEffect to access it everytime it changes. see my code for explanation.